# Displaying a list of files from a remote EC2 instance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, file-upload, permissions

I'm running two AWS EC2 instances (Ubuntu):

An admin interface (1) where users can view a list of files which reside in a directory on the other instance (2).

When testing locally, I can view files from another directory within my site using a basic php script:

```
$path = "upload_directory/“;
$files = scandir($path);
foreach($files as $file) {
    if ($file[0] != '.') $nothidden[] = $file;
}
for ($x=0;$x<count($nothidden);$x++){
${'file'.$x} = $nothidden[$x]; echo $nothidden[$x];
}
```

However, this obviously doesn't work when I run the script on another instance (one which is distinct from where the files are located), where the $path is changed:

```
$path = "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/upload_directory/
```

I'm not entirely sure what my next step should be. Is it merely a case of changing the outbound security settings on the directory which contains the files, or is it a more complex issue than this?

Unfortunately combining the two instances isn't a practical solution at the moment.

Comment: If you share files between instances, why not store the files in S3 or EFS?

Comment: Hi Marcin. The instance which stores the files also performs other functions, so my preference would be to keep them there. If it's not possible then I will have to look at an alternative like an S3 bucket.

Comment: EFS would allow you to access the files seamlessly from multiple instances, as it is just a network filesystem.

Comment: OK, so it sounds a more effective way of storing files than relying on another instance. Assuming I could implement it, the question remains - will I be able to display the files using the method above, or will I still need to play around with security? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what your code does. But if you used EFS, then it does not matter what instances produces the links to it.

Comment: I will try integrating it. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Install S3FS using instrctions from https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse.

Mount as local file system and configure aws keys having read and write permission to S3 bucket

```
/usr/local/bin/s3fs -o allow_other bucket /mnt/s3fs/pathlocal
```

on both ec2.
Do the below on both ec2:

if EC2 is attached with IAM profile having read and write permission to S3 bucket

```
/usr/local/bin/s3fs -o allow_other bucket /mnt/s3fs/pathlocal -o iam_role='role-name'
```

You can add mount script in **/etc/rc.local** to auto mount at boot time.